# Can I cast Rootgrapple via Leaf-Crowned Elder?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

[Leaf-Crowned Elder](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Leaf-Crowned%20Elder) has:

> Kinship — At the beginning of your upkeep, you may look at the top card of your library. If it shares a **creature type** with Leaf-Crowned Elder, you may reveal it. If you do, you may play that card without paying its mana cost.

Leaf-Crowned Elder is a Treefolk Shaman. Does it allow me to cast [Rootgrapple](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Rootgrapple), a Tribal Instant — Treefolk, from the top of my deck?

I wouldn't have this doubt if it said *subtype* instead of *creature type* (in this case I'd know I can).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Yes, Leaf-Crowned Elder's ability allows you to cast Rootgrapple.**

The term "creature type" is defined in [rule 302.3](https://mtg.fandom.com/wiki/Creature):

> Creature subtypes are always a single word and are listed after a long dash: “Creature — Human Soldier,” “Artifact Creature — Golem,” and so on. **Creature subtypes are also called creature types.** Creatures may have multiple subtypes. See rule 205.3m for the complete list of creature types.

So, when Leaf-Crowned Elder's ability says "creature types", it is referring to creature subtypes.

In addition, [rule 308.2](https://mtg.fandom.com/wiki/Tribal) explicitly states that tribal subtypes are the same as creature subtypes.

> Tribal subtypes are always a single word and are listed after a long dash: “Tribal Enchantment — Merfolk.” **The set of tribal subtypes is the same as the set of creature subtypes; these subtypes are called creature types.** Tribals may have multiple subtypes. See rule 205.3m for the complete list of creature types.

Comment: Thank you. By the way, if Elder's rules text had "card subtype" written instead of "creature type", would it be the same?

Comment: That kind of thing would just say "subtype", and it would work a little differently if you had a creature that was also another type, like artifact. Then it would allow you to cast non-creature artifacts with the same artifact subtype as that artifact creature. For example , if you controlled a Gingerbrute, that alternate ability would allow you to cast Golden Egg.